# What is SQL Server CE's datetime format?

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-ce

I have a `DateTime` in my c# code, and when I'm trying to pass it to SQL Server CE, it returns a `SqlCeExpcetion`, I guess it's because of the format...here's what my query gets alike

```
SELECT * FROM [Receipt] WHERE [Created] > 3/21/2014 5:47:36 PM
```

the actual code is

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + TABLE_NAME + "] WHERE [" + CREATED_COLUMN + "] > " + startTime.ToString();
```

What format shall I pass to have a normal query?

Comment: If you passed it as an SQL parameter then you would avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ISO DateTime Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):  `'2014-03-21T17:47:36'` and insert the date inside the quote '' as a varchar

In c#:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE [{1}] > '{2}'", TABLE_NAME, CREATED_COLUMN, startTime.ToString("s"));
```

Comment: @user3279938 the date must be inside the '' as a varchar

Comment: ITYM `2014-03-21T17:47:36` if you're referring to ISO 8601 as shown in [datetime (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Comment: damn, your'e right))) how come i've missed that))) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the ODBC canonical format, or even better use SqlCeParameter with a parameterized Query.

```
{ts ‘2009-05-11 23:00:00’}
```

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2009/06/scripting-sql-datetime-fields-and.html